Proving $x^3$ is Big-O of $x^2$ as $x \rightarrow 0$
EDIT: I have attempted the question again and posted an answer in a separate post if you scroll blow. Can you please check my NEW working?
The definition I have is that $f(x)$ is Big-O of $g(x)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$ if there exists $K, \delta >0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq K |g(x)|$ when $0<|x-x_0|< \delta$.
In this case $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=x^2$ and $x_0=0$.
I need to show that there exist $K, \delta >0$ such that if $0 < |x| < \delta$, then $|x^3| \leq K |x^2|$.
I know that if $\delta < 1$, then $|x^3| < |x^2|$, which gives $0 < |x| < \delta$ implies that $|x^3| \leq |x^2| = 1 \cdot |x^2|$ where $K=1$
Does that mean I have proved this as there exists a $K=1 > 0$ where this is true and there exists a $\delta > 0$ where this is true, namely $0 < \delta < 1$?

@YvesDaoust So I am correct? It seems like you set $\delta = 1$? I believe that from the definition of Big-0 that I just need to show that this works for AT LEAST ONE value of $\delta$, so could I just make it simpler by choosing $\delta = \frac{1}{2} $ for example?

This is what I have done now.
$0 < |x| < \delta \implies |x^3| = |x|^3 \leq |x|^2 = |x^2| = 1 \cdot |x^2|$, so there exists a $K>0$ and $\delta>0$ satisfying requirements where $K=1$ and $0<$$\delta \leq 1$

@YvesDaoust That is because in definition it says that there exists $K, \delta > 0$ so we can pick right? It's still okay to leave it like I did though right? I can't upvote you by the way because I don't have enough reputation myself. Sorry.

@YvesDaoust Okay I will do that. Could I say $\delta = 0.5$ or any positive number less than $1$ also?

@YvesDaoust Because the inequality $|x^3| < |x^2|$ only holds if $|x| < 1$
